# How should I access a service in a react-redux app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I'm learning React and Redux. I've done a fair bit of reading and created a basic app. I now want to create a simple calculator app as a more advanced training exercise.

The calculator app will be very basic, ie. buttons for the numbers and operations and a simple text field to display the number being typed or the running total. It will emulate a simple desk calculator. That is, if you click the 5 button, a 5 will appear in the text field. If you now click 6, the display changes to 56. Click +, 3, 1 in succession and the display now shows 31. Click = and 87 will be displayed.

The business logic of the calculating engine (the Calculator) is a service and can be separated from the app itself. There should only be one instance of the Calculator in the app. What I'd like to know is how to make the Calculator available to the app, esp. in the reducers. The calculator needs to hold some state, eg. what numbers have been entered so far.

In React-Redux the state is represented by a single object and made available through the store. Should the Calculator be one item of state? (The other item would be the current value to display.) Given that the Calculator never changes, ie. it always points to the same reference, does this make sense? (The internal state of the Calculator will change, but this is largely invisible to the app.) Would this mean that my reducers would always accept the Calculator as state and pass it back? I don't think I want to make a copy each time.

Or is it better to make the Calculator available via some sort of Singleton?

Or is there another way more in keeping with the React-Redux idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further reading on Singletons in Javascript (ES6) and building on @jiujitsucoder's answer, I have come up with my own solution that seems to be working well.

The Calculator class is made available as a singleton to other components of the app.

`calculator.js`

```
class Calculator {
    constructor() {
        this.runningTotal = 0;
    }
    currentValue() {
        return this.runningTotal;
    }
    operation() { ... }
    ...
    }
}

let instance = new Calculator();
export default instance
```

The reducer (for example) receives an action corresponding to a key press in the UI and instructs the Calculator accordingly.

`reducer.js`

```
import Calculator from './calculator';
const initialValue = 0;
export default function(state = initialValue, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PROCESS_DIGIT:
            Calculator.digit(action.digit);
            return Calculator.currentValue();
        case PROCESS_OPERATOR:
            Calculator.operator(action.operator);
            return Calculator.currentValue();
        }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think with something like a calculator in react/redux I would create a case in my reducer to handle the '=' button being pressed, with both the current value and the expression passed in through the action object. I would envision a reducer like this:

```
const initialState = {
  totalValue: 0
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EQUAL_PRESSED:
      // Do your work here to call your calculator service.
      // you can pass in action.currentTotal and action.expressionToEval
      // to whatever functions will do the actual work and return a new 
      // total.
      var newTotal = calcEngine(action.currentTotal, action.expressionToEval);
      return {
        ...state,
        totalValue: newTotal
      };
  }
}

export function equalPressed(currentTotal, expressionToEval) {
  return {
    type: EQUAL_PRESSED,
    currentTotal: currentTotal,
    expressionToEval: expressionToEval
  };
}
```

then in my react component I would access the redux state tree and grab the new `totalValue` to be displayed wherever you are showing the result.

Comment: A couple of questions: (a) where do I source the calcEngine from in your example? (b) I envisioned the Calculator holding state, eg. the running total, history, etc. This would allow me to re-use it elsewhere. Is this a bad idea? You seem to be suggesting that all such state should be in the store. Thanks.

Comment: @dave the calcEngine I put in there to show a service being referenced to do the actual math work of adding/subtracting/multiplying etc. You could do all of that work in the reducer or in the action creator equalPressed() but that would get messy pretty quickly.

Comment: @dave second, the rule of thumb I've always used when deciding where state should live is that if it should survive a component unloading or a page refresh, it should live in redux. I would say the running total and history would both qualify to live in redux. Something like "is the file menu open or closed" doesn't necessarily have to live in redux and could easily get reset to a default state on reload with hardly anyone noticing.

Comment: \@jiujitsucoder - thanks for the responses. I get the idea of state living in redux (or being managed by it). I feel that the calc engine should hold most of this as it should understand it and the UI/reducers should not. Which appears to be what you've sketched out in your code. So if we put it into the service (as we both seem to think), how do we manage access to this service. Is it part of the store? In your code, you just use it. Where did you get it from? Thanks.

Comment: @dave yeah I looked at the calculator as a separate service. I like the way you've set it up. The only other piece I would change though is taking the running total out of the calculator service and passing that in. It will add a parameter to your functions but it will make the whole calculator service stateless which will make it easier to test. It's up to you, however. That's just my humble opinion.